# Html Box Around live input

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to get a box around 2 different fields of input the script pings a game server and brings back information but pings 2 servers i want them to be put inside a box instead of just laying on the website messy

```
<?php
// Include the main class file
require '../GameQ.php';

// Define your servers,
// see list.php for all supported games and identifiers.
$servers = array(
    array(
        'id' => 'BF4',
        'type' => 'bf4',
        'host' => '192.223.29.138:47200',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'GMOD',
        'type' => 'gmod',
        'host' => '31.186.251.28:27015',
    )
);


// Call the class, and add your servers.
$gq = new GameQ();
$gq->addServers($servers);

// You can optionally specify some settings
$gq->setOption('timeout', 4); // Seconds

// You can optionally specify some output filters,
// these will be applied to the results obtained.
$gq->setFilter('normalise');

// Send requests, and parse the data
$results = $gq->requestData();


// Some functions to print the results
function print_results($results) {

    foreach ($results as $id => $data) {

        printf("<h2>%s</h2>\n", $id);
        print_table($data);
    }

}

function print_table($data) {

    $gqs = array('gq_online', 'gq_address', 'gq_port', 'gq_prot', 'gq_type');


    if (!$data['gq_online']) {
        printf("<p>The server did not respond within the specified time.</p>\n");
        return;
    }

    print("<table><thead><tr><td>Variable</td><td>Value</td></tr></thead><tbody>\n");

    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {

        if (is_array($val)) continue;

        $cls = empty($cls) ? ' class="uneven"' : '';

        if (substr($key, 0, 3) == 'gq_') {
            $kcls = (in_array($key, $gqs)) ? 'always' : 'normalise';
            $key = sprintf("<span class=\"key-%s\">%s</span>", $kcls, $key);
        }

        printf("<tr%s><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", $cls, $key, $val);
    }

    print("</tbody></table>\n");

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Game List</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />          
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Game List</h1>
    <div id="chat">
    Server List. <br/>
        Click <a href="list.php">here</a> for a list of supported games.
    </div>

<?php
    print_results($results);
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

the css

```
body {
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
}
table td {
    color: #cccccc; // OR WHATEVER
}
h1 {
    color: #00ff00;
}
#chat {
color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS to change the required font color.  Text doesn't come in as black, that's just the default font color for browsers.

```
table td {
    color: #123456; // OR WHATEVER
}
```

Comment: hey thanks that worked but if i check at the top it has a label called bf4 it doesn't change like the input?

Comment: @LinuxUnix I'd have to see your code to answer that

Comment: @LinuxUnix, nm I see above.  just use <style type="text/css"> // CSS </style>  Otherwise you can use what you have and move your CSS into a new file style.css

Comment: check above again dude.